# Creating an XML file using XSD in SSIS

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd, ssis-2012

I am working a requirement where, i have extract the database and write it in XML file.
this XML should be created based on the XSD before writing it in the XML file.
"Validating a XML file against an XSD is available" but i coudn't find help upon the internet for this.

Can anyone help me out with some ideas of creating the same in SSIS?

Comment: Did you check out `XML Task` and go to `XML Task Editor` >> `Input`  >> `OperationType` and select `Validate`? Link [Validate XML file XSD](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.ca/2012/08/validating-xml-file-against-xsd-with.html) might help